# CustomAnimation not working when inside a class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the [simple_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations) package and want to reuse the following code:

```
 return CustomAnimation<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 60),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 225),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        control: (shouldShow)
            ? CustomAnimationControl.play
            : CustomAnimationControl.playReverse,
        builder: (context, child, value) {
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(value, 0),
            child: child,
          );
        });
```

So I made it a widget like so:

```
/// sidebar animator for showing / hiding a sidebar
class SidebarAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool shouldShow;
  final Widget child;
  final InfiniteNoteController controller;

  const SidebarAnimation(
      {Key? key,
      required this.shouldShow,
      required this.child,
      required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomAnimation<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 60),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 225),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        control: (shouldShow)
            ? CustomAnimationControl.play
            : CustomAnimationControl.playReverse,
        builder: (context, child, value) {
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(value, 0),
            child: child,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

The widget doesn't even show if I use the SidebarAnimation widget but works fine if I just use the first chunk of code. What am I not doing right?

Comment: try with using `key`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference. I added a key: key to the CustomAnimation and when using the SidebarAnimation, added the parameter ValueKey('something'). The widget still isn't showing. The animation works though, I can print out the values but the child just isn't there.

Comment: What is `InfiniteNoteController`?

Comment: Oh I just haven't removed it. But it shouldn't affect anything.